# How to make image transparent/Opaque for image render

Tags: rendering, transparency

I have an image I'm trying to make it transparent. I have tried both methods, importing images as planes and adding it as a background.

importing it as a background I can lower the alpha, but it wont render.
Adding it as a: Image as planes, It does render, but the transparent setting I have chosen wont make it transparent/opaque.

So what Im trying to do, is, have my main image in the background, and trying to lower the opacity of the image in the front, and render it.

[image]

Comment: you can't render a Reference or Background image, but you can render an Image as Planes, then if you want to make it partially opaque you need to lower down the Principled Alpha value or mix it with a Transparent node

Comment: OK, thanks for that. I believe this is the node set up, but my shader viewport is so much different from my render. https://ibb.co/bs45RPB

Comment: because you have given a color to your world but you've also enabled the Render > Film > Transparent option, with Transparent enabled you won't see the world in your render

Comment: All good thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't render a *Reference* or a *Background* image, but you can render an *Image as Planes*, then if you want to make it partially opaque you need to lower down the *Principled Alpha* value or mix it with a *Transparent* node.

As for your *World*: you have given a color to your *World* but you've also enabled the *Render > Film > Transparent* option. With *Transparent* enabled you won't see the *World* in your render.